# What are some methods to secure Application pages?

Tags: application-pages, security

I'm jumping into SharePoint 2010 (first SP version for me) and I'm building some application pages.  I'm trying to secure the pages by dropping a web.config in the dir with role authorization.  Is this the proper way?  What's the standard way to secure application pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the remarks:

In general, use LayoutsPageBase as a base class for pages that should only be accessible to authenticated users with certain rights. For pages to which even unauthenticated users should have access, use the parent class UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.aspx